# prove that $f$ is increasing iff $f^\prime >0$ for all $x \in I$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

In the first part of the proof, the author says $\lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f^\prime(c) \ge 0$, but what we really want to get is $f^\prime (x) \ge 0$

So, is it okay if I  say $\lim_{y \to x} \frac {f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f^\prime(x) \ge 0$?

The atuhor uses the notation, $c$, as a cluster point before, so I am not sure if it is allowed to replace c by x.

Comment: $c$ is in $I$, just like $x$ is in $I$. There really isn't a difference. The statement remains true for all $c$ in $I$.

Comment: To word the above comment differently: it doesn't matter if it's $f^{\prime}(x)$ or $f^{\prime}(c)$ which is $\geq 0$. What matters is this: if you take any **arbitrary** number in an interval $I$ with a differentiable and increasing $f$, you end up with a non-negative value for $f^{\prime}$ at that point. Since $x$ and $c$ are **arbitrary** numbers in $I$ and the derivative is nonnegative at one of these points, the proof is good.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the derivative,
$$f^\prime(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.$$
The proof's argument is that 
$$\frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\ge 0,$$
for all $x$ and $c$ in $I$. Therefore, in particular, this is true in the limit as $x$ goes to $c$. Since that is the definition of $f'(c)$ to begin with, it follows that
$$f'(c) \ge 0, $$
for all $c$ in $I$. The variable $c$ is just a dummy variable, if you prefer you can call it $y$.